# How to loop foreach in laravel dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Am just learning Laravel and I have this logic were in I want to display array of total items based from user, to explain this further here is my database

user table

[image]

items table

[image]

this is my current code

```
public function display()
    {
       
            $users = User::where('type', 'Shop')->get();

            foreach($users as $user){
                $shop_id = $user['id'];
                $shop_name = $user['name'];
            }
            $total = Item::where('user_id', $shop_id)->sum('total');
            $shops =[
                ['Name' => $shop_name, 'total' => $total],
            ];

            return response()->json([
                "shops" =>$shops
            ], 200);

    }
```

and here is my sample output:

[image]

am only getting 1 object instead of 2 as I have two shops how to loop this dynamically.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
 $shops[] = ['Name' => $shop_name, 'total' => $total];
```

to push all the shops into one array.

You are currently overriding the hole array.

UPDATE: Also move the sql part into the foreach:

```
 foreach($users as $user){
     $shop_id = $user['id'];
     $shop_name = $user['name'];
     $total = Item::where('user_id', $shop_id)->sum('total');
     $shops[] =['Name' => $shop_name, 'total' => $total];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Am still getting one object instead of two

Comment: Thanks for the replay but still am getting only one object.

Answer (score 3):

the `$shops` and `$total` variable is not in foreach loop that's because it returns only one row. and you must use `$shops[]` .

```
public function display()
    {
       
            $users = User::where('type', 'Shop')->get();

            foreach($users as $user){
                $shop_id = $user['id'];
                $shop_name = $user['name'];
                $total = Item::where('user_id', $shop_id)->sum('total');
                $shops[] =['Name' => $shop_name, 'total' => $total];
            }
           
            return response()->json([
                "shops" =>$shops
            ], 200);

    }
```

but the best and clean way is to use laravel relationship

in User model:

```
public function items()
{
return $this->hasMany(Item::class) ;
}
```

and display controller :

```
public function display()
 {
   $shops = User::where('type', 'Shop')->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($user){
               return ['name'=>$user->name ,
                       'total'=> $user->items->sum('total')
             ]});

  return response()->json(["shops" =>$shops], 200);

 }
```

Comment: thanks for the replay on your first suggested answer its still showing 1 object. I already have a relationship on my tables [users belongs to items] if possible I don't want it to refactor. Maybe you have other suggestion? thanks

Comment: are you sure you have two user? get dd of  $users variable and check if you have two rows